# Is it correct and natural to use the present continuous after "hope" to refer to the future?

Tags: present-continuous

Could you tell me if it is correct and natural to use the present continuous after *hope* to refer to the future? For example:

> I hope **it's not raining** when we go out this time tomorrow.

I've only seen the present simple or future simple used to refer to the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is perfectly normal.

The present continuous can always refer to future events, especially they are a direct consequence of the present situation and certain to occur:  It is rather like the "going to" future:

> I'm playing tennis tomorrow (because the court is booked and its in my diary).

With "hope" the present tense often refers to future events.  "

> I hope you pass your exam.

If you are hoping for something that will take some time, then present continuous is fine:

> I hope *I'm* leading the parade tomorrow.  Coach said he'd pick a leader tonight.

Your example is very natural, with "raining" functioning almost like an adjective to describe the weather.